# return value asynchronous method

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, return

I have a method that passed an array of object call on each object an asynchronous method:

```
function method(objs){
  for(obj in objs){
    obj.asyncMethod()
  }
}
```

I have this idea that every function should return a value, but in this case the value should be based on the result of the async method so it's quite impossible.

**is it a bad practic not to return a value (especially in library)?**

if yes, there are solutions?

Comment: Make your `method` asynchronous too - take a callback function as a parameter and call it from the `obj.asyncMethod` callback handler.

Comment: should i accept a callback also for `method`? and when it should be executed since I don't know when each `asyncMethod` is completed?

Comment: It only makes sense to pass in a function as a callback _if_ `asyncMethod` is coded to expect a callback. As described there isn't enough information about how your code works in order to provide a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function should only return a value if it needs to return a value. There is absolutely nothing wrong with writing a function that does not return anything.

To answer your other question: no, there is no solution to this since inherently the `method` function will return before the asynchronous methods execute.

What would you even return? The code will go through n iterations in that `for` loop so how would you know which one to even return?

Answer (score 2):

It is not bad practice to not return a value for async operations, it is expected. Accept a callback function as argument. There are quite a few built in and external libraries in node.js that have methods which accept callbacks as arguments.

Comment: the callback can be passed to `method` but it is set as a callback for `asyncMethod` not for `method`, should i accept a callback also for `method`? and when it should be executed since I don't know when each `asyncMethod` is completed?

Comment: There are a number of different ways you could handle that. One idea off the top of my head would be to keep track of the number of iterations of the `for` loop and also increment a numerical value for every completion of `asyncMethod` then compare them to know when all of the executions have completed. We do something along these lines in our current project so we can accept an "onReady" type of method.